# Ajax/jQuery Abort on timeout

Tags: jquery, ajax, abort

Newbie - Quesiton -

Problem trying to solve: In case there are some open connections that aren't closed by XMLHttprequest, we want to abort them.

In a javascript file, where there are Ajax calls, I need to start a timer for each call, and clear the timer in both success and failure callbacks. Want to make sure that - if timer fires then it means request has not returned, so it should be aborted.  For cases where inspite of the abort, the request may come back - want to discard them. Want to add a flag  which checks  success and failure callbacks before processing, and handles appropriately.

Want to add a timer like this :

```
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {         // Start a timer. If triggered,
                           timedout = true; // set a flag and then
                           request.abort(); // abort the request.
                       },
                       timeout);            // time specified
```

But in the given existing code like below, I finding it hard on understanding where to start my timer and abort.

```
        this.ajaxCall = function(urlSuffix, type, data, successCallback, errorCallback, callbackParam, logFlag)
 {
    if (!successCallback) {
        throw "A successCallback must be supplied";
    }
    if (!errorCallback) {
        throw "An errorCallback must be supplied";
    }
    var st = 0;
    if (logFlag !== false)
        st = LogMessageTestCL(urlSuffix + " - start: " + type, -1);
    $.ajax({
        url: urlRoot + urlSuffix,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        cache: false,

        success: function(msg) {
            try {
                if (logFlag !== false)
                    LogMessageTestCL(urlSuffix + " - end: " + type, st);
                successCallback(msg, callbackParam);
            }
            catch (e) {
                // this will only fail when the calling page is unloaded before the call returns, so no need to log this
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr,status) { 
            try {
                if (logFlag !== false)
                    LogMessageTestCL(urlSuffix + " - error end: " + type, st);
                if (status === "timeout") {
                    alert("30 sec time out");   
                    LogMessageTestCL("callback timed out");
                    return;
                }
                else if (status === "error") {
                    if (xhr.status != 200) {
                        errorCallback(xhr, callbackParam);
                    }
                }
                else
                    errorCallback(xhr, callbackParam);
            }
            catch (e) {
                // this will only fail when the calling page is unloaded before the call returns, so no need to log this
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to implement the logic yourself and the timeout option is provided by jquery, look at the documentation of [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) there is an option called `timeout`.

Ex:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: '',
    data: '',
    timeout: 30000, //time in milliseconds - 30000 equals 30 seconds,
    ......
})
```

Comment: Thank you Arun for responding. On top of the timeout given by JQuery - we do want to add this abort. Is there a way to explicitly do so?

Comment: @user1834443 what do you mean by `abort`? what should happen then

Comment: I meant - abort the request - like xhr.abort() - do you think this is not necessary?

Comment: @user1834443 so you do not want to call the fail callback in case of timeout error

Comment: I want to start and clear a timer for both success and failure callbacks. If timer fires then it means request has not returned, and in those cases abort the request.

Comment: Thank you Arun. I will try this and come back.

Comment: Please bear with me again. I did something like this for the purpose of having to start my own timer for each call and clearing the timer upon success and error callbacks. If the timer had fired, that  means request has not returned(which is what I want to see if the timer fires).

Comment: @user1834443 can you prepare a jsfiddle example

Comment: I added the setTimeOut and function Mytimeout. I want to set a flag isDone in that function after 30 seconds .  (I could probably name it better). If that timer kicks in - that means my request has not come back and there are some open connections remaining. The problem I am troubleshooting is very intermittent. Is this a correct way of adding a timer.

Comment: In house we don't see problems but it happens at a customer location and when we debugged there - they have some open connections from xhr - which is why we want to start a timer for each call, and clear the timer in both success and failure callbacks.  If timer fires then it means request has not returned, so it should be aborted.

Comment: did my jsfiddle make any sense? @ arun-p-johny :(

Comment: All i want to do is - if any of the requests are taking time more than "x" seconds - (say, 30 seconds) - I want to abort those requests with my own timer.